# How to return data from inside promise.all

Tags: node.js, return

```
findCustomerOrders(customerId) {
    return APIService.getCustomerOrders(this, customerId)
      .then((data) =>  {
        data.map(order => {
          return Promise.all([APIService.getShippingAddress(this, order.id), APIService.getProducts(this,order.id), APIService.getCustomerById(this, customerId)])
          .then((returnedData)=>{
            return buildOrder(returnedData);
          });
      });
   });
  }
```

The function where the data is to be returned is

```
findCustomerOrders(1)
.then((final) =>{console.log(final)});
```

I have to return the data which is returned by buildOrder Function, Due to Promise.all() I am not able to get the data back and it is showing the returned value as undefined.
buildOrder function is correctly returning the value but the problem is with the above block, that too only with the return statements
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this from my mentor :

```
findCustomerOrders(customerId) {
    return APIService.getCustomerOrders(this, customerId)
      .then(orders => orders.map(order => Promise.all([APIService.getShippingAddress(this, order.id), APIService.getProducts(this, order.id), APIService.getCustomerById(this, customerId)])
        .then((returnedData) => {
          return buildOrder(order);
        })))
      .then(promises => Promise.all(promises));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't return the `Promise.all()`. Instead, just call a `.then()` at the end of it like this:

```
findCustomerOrders(customerId) {
return APIService.getCustomerOrders(this, customerId)
  .then((data) =>  {
    data.map(order => {
      Promise.all([APIService.getShippingAddress(this, order.id), APIService.getProducts(this,order.id), APIService.getCustomerById(this, customerId)]).then((returnedData) => {
        return buildOrder(returnedData);
      })
   });
 });
}
```

Also, is `buildOrder(returnedData)` being passed somewhere else? Because if it isn't then you should just call it outright and not return it.

Comment: Yes the data returned by buildOrder has to be returned back

Comment: Can u please show me the way to  code without using returning Promise.all

Comment: What order do the APIService functions need to be called in? And also bear in mind that Promise.all() will pass an array of the values in its .then statement. Does buildOrder accept an array of values as its argument?

Comment: Yes buildOrder accepts array and it is returning the result correctly. I checked it

Comment: Where is `this` coming from as well? `this ` doesn't bind to arrow functions, so you may have to declare the function the other way.

Comment: They are working fine. this is from the constructor data. The only problem here is with return

Comment: `.map` returns a new array. Assign it to something.

Answer (score 0):

if by return you mean to use the data returned by `buildOrder` after calling `findCustomerOrders`, you could just `.then` it. Just make sure that function is returning a Promise.

```
findCustomerOrders(1).then((data) => {
   // data should be what buildOrder resolve to.
})
```

data.map returns an array of Promises, each will resolve to the buildOrder result. So, you should return a Promise there too:

```
findCustomerOrders(customerId) {
    return APIService.getCustomerOrders(this, customerId)
      .then((data) =>  {
        return Promise.all(data.map(order => {
          return Promise.all([APIService.getShippingAddress(this, order.id), APIService.getProducts(this,order.id), APIService.getCustomerById(this, customerId)])
          .then((returnedData)=>{
            return buildOrder(returnedData);
          });
      }));
   });
  }
```

Comment: I tried the return statement before data.map but it didn't work

Comment: try returning a Promise, use Promise.all with the data.map.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using promise.all then there is multiple output from function, so you should write all output variable in array.

```
findCustomerOrders(customerId) {
return APIService.getCustomerOrders(this, customerId)
  .then((data) =>  {
    data.map(order => {
      return Promise.all([APIService.getShippingAddress(this, order.id), APIService.getProducts(this,order.id), APIService.getCustomerById(this, customerId)])
      .then(([result1, result2, result3])=>{
        return buildOrder([result1, result2, result3]);
      });
  });
   });
  }
```

it may be works, it will not gives your value to be undefined if value is not undefined.

Comment: I used them in buildOrder function. Thats not the case here. The only problem here is returning the value of buildOrder.

Comment: so you have an issue in buildOrder function, which you didn't mentioned in your post. please post full code, so i can check your requirement

Comment: As per my view your issue due to the undefined value pass to buildOrder function. try to my method and change buildOrder function according to that. its works for me, so you should try it.